# How to view this specific data in page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to build a blog website as follow:

Category Model

```
public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public String CategoryName { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    }
```

Article Model

```
public class Article
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public byte[] BlogImage{ get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreationDate{ get; set; }
        public int? CategoryID{ get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

So, how can I send data in ActionResult function and view blog card in page like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JqqU.png)?

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (MvcBlogContext context = new MvcBlogContext())
            {
                 // how to code here?
            }
        }
```

```
<div class="row">
     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
           <div class="col-md-4">
            // how to view category name here?
           </div>
     }
</div>

<div class="row">
     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
           <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="post post-widget"
                     // how to view from 2nd to 4th blog here?
                </div>
           </div>
     }
</div>
```

Can you help me about this?

Comment: This is too broad to answer easily and is also at least two questions in one. It also helps to show what you have tried so far and say what problems you are having.

Answer (score 0):

To answer one of your questions - selecting the first entry and then the rest you could try

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Take(1))
```

for the first row, and then

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Skip(1))
```

for the rest. It assumes that the data in your model is ordered appropriately.